# How to Hide/ Remove/ Avoid System App (non UI) getting listed/shown in Android app drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk

I'm working on a system app which not contain any user interface(service only). I start my service on boot. And I'm killing the launcher activity immediately by calling the `finish()` method.
Also I'm using the following code to remove the icon from launcher/app drawer.

> PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
>
> ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
>
> packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

No issue with the implementation all work fine. But I couldn't reinstall apk on the device which already have this app installed unless uninstall the app and install it freshly.

My question is there are lot of apps in the Android devices which is not listed in the app drawer especially system apps & some downloaded apps too.(example few Keyboard apps downloaded from playstore).

I wonder is this only way to achieve this? Or is there are any other ways to declare the app as non UI app (to avoid getting listed/shown in app drawer) some where in AndroidMainfest?

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/blackcj/AndroidCustomKeyboard) keyboard system app built in android studio. It should give you a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. Completely remove this line. Because this is not the best idea to hide your app icon from the app drawer. It may cause some problems during the app updating process as you mentioned.

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
     packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Also, remove the following "category.LAUNCHER" line from you main activity intent filter tag(on Mainifest.xml)

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Make sure you have ".action.MAIN" inside your main activity  tag

For an example, you can simply replace this code with your current  tag of your main activity. manifest

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" /> <!-- optional--> 
</intent-filter>
```

After this, your app won't be listed in the App drawer since your app doesn't contain launchable activity. In this way, you can also avoid reinstalling/updating issue that you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

In the android manifest for the relevant activity remove the Launcher intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I couldn't compile it in Android studio if I remove.

Comment: Couldn't even compile says "Default Activity not found"